# Discriminated unions in modules

Tags: f#

The following works as I would expect.

```
type Result =
    | Success
    | Failure

type Response  =
    | Result of Result

let response = Response.Result <| Result.Success

match response with
    | Result result ->
        match result with
        | Result.Success -> printfn "Success"
        | Result.Failure -> printfn "Failure"
```

However, when I place some of it in a module:

```
module Module =
    type Result =
        | Success
        | Failure

    type Response  =
        | Result of Result        

let response = Module.Response.Result <| Module.Result.Success // <- ERROR HERE
```

I get the error:

> The field, constructor or member 'Success' is not defined

And it also means that I can't do matching like:

```
match response with
    | Module.Result result ->
        match result with
        | Module.Result.Success -> printfn "Success"
        | Module.Result.Failure -> printfn "Failure"
```

which fails with

> This is not a constructor or literal, or a constructor is being used incorrectly

(To get this to fail, some additional code needs to be added such that `Module` has a `createResponse`:

```
let createResponse b = 
    if b
    then Response.Result <| Result.Success
    else Response.Result <| Result.Failure
```

and `response` in the code outside the module is then `let response = Module.createResponse true`.

Shouldn't I be able to achieve the same result regardless of putting some code in a module?

Comment: Seems like a bug because `Success` even shows up in Intellisense.

Comment: Yes maybe it's really a bug

Answer (score 1):

Actually fully qualified name `Module.Result.Success` should work where first error happens. Compiler confusion comes because you gave the same name to two different things.
This line will compile:

```
let response = Module.Response.Result <| Module.Success
```

And you can do pattern matching this way:

```
match response with
    | Module.Result result ->
        match result with
        | Module.Success -> printfn "Success"
        | Module.Failure -> printfn "Failure"
```

In the last example: you are matching `response` value against `Module.Result` with parameter `result`. It could be only of type `Module.Response` because the single case of this type - namely `Module.Result` - has a parameter. And because this parameter is of type `Module.Result` it could be matched against two cases of this type: `Module.Success` and `Module.Failure`. It looks and sound confusing because it is. The same name `"Result"` is given both to discriminated union type and to the case-id of another discriminate union type. I would change `Response` type to something like this:

```
type Response  =
    | RespResult of Result
```

Comment: Suppose there is another type in Module that also has Success and Failure. How would the compiler be able to discern between the two unless it is explicitly instructed to? How come `Result.Success` in the non-module case becomes `Module.Success` in the module case?

Comment: Edited answer to clarify names collision

Comment: @lejon. Yes, looks like a bug. Fully qualified name should work. But the answer provides a workaround at least.

Comment: Alright, I will report it. For the workaround to be more general, I think the `Result` needs to be `Result<T>` to avoid collisions with other DU type with `Success`.